# How to put JOutlookBar into a JPanel in Java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

How can I put a `JOutlookBar` into a `JPanel`?

Here is my code:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("JOutlookBar Test");
JOutlookBar outlookBar = new JOutlookBar();
outlookBar.addBar("One", getDummyPanel1("one"));
outlookBar.addBar("Two", getDummyPanel2("Two"));
outlookBar.addBar("Three", getDummyPanel3("Three"));
outlookBar.addBar("Four", getDummyPanel4("Four"));
outlookBar.addBar("Five", getDummyPanel5("Five"));
outlookBar.setVisibleBar(0);
frame.getContentPane().add(outlookBar);
frame.setSize(800, 600);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `frame.setVisible(true);` allowed me to view your code working correctly.

Below is full working example of the code you provided, copy and paste it into a file named Library.java and it'll be grand!

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Library {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JOutlookBar Test");
        JPanel left = new JPanel();
        JPanel center = new JPanel();
        JOutlookBar outlookBar = new JOutlookBar();

        outlookBar.addBar("One", getDummyPanel1("one"));
        outlookBar.addBar("Two", getDummyPanel1("Two"));
        outlookBar.addBar("Three", getDummyPanel1("Three"));
        outlookBar.addBar("Four", getDummyPanel1("Four"));
        outlookBar.addBar("Five", getDummyPanel1("Five"));
        outlookBar.setVisibleBar(0);

        //Add outlookbar to left panel
        left.add(outlookBar);

        //Add some content to center panel...
        center.add(new JTextArea());

        //Add left and center panels with layout styles
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(left, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        //Show JFrame
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static JPanel getDummyPanel1(String num) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JButton("num"));
        return panel;
    }
}
```

Comment: thnx,bt its not working actualy i want to add in my designing jpanel

Comment: You want to add JOutlookBar to a JPanel? This is easy... From my code above you simply must say JPanel.add(JOutlookBar) - Otherwise you're going to need to be more specific.

Comment: i want to add my gui designing jPanel1 and it is in init method

Comment: instead of frame i want ro used my designing gui jpanel1